# UITextFieldDelegate not working for childViewController Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfielddelegate

I added a `SecondViewController` as a child after pressing a button. The code below is the button action inside `MainViewController`.

```
@IBAction func btnPressed(_ sender: Any) {    
    addChildViewController(SecondViewController())

    view.superview?.addSubview(SecondViewController().view)

    SecondViewController().view.frame = (view.superview?.bounds)!
                SecondViewController().view.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]

    SecondViewController().didMove(toParentViewController: self)
}
```

Inside `SecondViewController`, I set `UITextFieldDelegate` like this

`class SecondViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {`

and I set textField delegate with view controller on my `xib`. Even tried with `myTextField.delegate = self`. This is my `shouldChangeCharactersIn range`

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
        print("While entering the characters this method gets called")
        return true;
    }
```

But that method never get called.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are doing is creating 5 different instances of `SecondViewController` - you are doing that by calling initializer (`SecondViewController()`) in each line

```
@IBAction func btnPressed(_ sender: Any) {    
    addChildViewController(SecondViewController()) // first instance created

    view.superview?.addSubview(SecondViewController().view) // second instance created

    SecondViewController().view.frame = (view.superview?.bounds)! // third instance created
    SecondViewController().view.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight] // fourth instance created

    SecondViewController().didMove(toParentViewController: self) // fifth instance created
}
```

Do instead

```
@IBAction func btnPressed(_ sender: Any) {   
    let secondViewController = SecondViewController()

    addChildViewController(secondViewController)
    view.superview?.addSubview(secondViewController.view)
    secondViewController.view.frame = (view.superview?.bounds)!
    secondViewController.view.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
    secondViewController.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
}
```